# Android Services, Threads and UI

Tags: android, multithreading, service

I have a ListActivity that starts a service. In this service, I started a thread that does some database query of up to 800 contacts, this seems to be slowing down or even hanging the UI sometimes. Should I be using AsyncTask instead? What is the proper way to handle this?

Comment: Just to add on, is it normal for the Activity View to "lag" a bit when there is an update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally services are running on UI-Thread.
But you had mentioned that you are using thread in services it mean your work is doing in background so there is no any possibility to block UI-Thread.

I think you had write a some code out of thread for update UI and that may be blocking your UI.

You can use `AsyncTask` instead of starting service and updating using thread because asynctask is doing same thing as background thread can do.

Comment: Currently I'm throttling the threads created because AsyncTask has a limit of 20 or something, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

Try incremental load of the contacts for your list. Querying so much data would of course slow your thread down.